# [auth][details] { "provider: credentials"} [auth] [cause] {TypeError: "ikm'} also data is undefined in login form

Tags: authentication, authorization, credentials, bcrypt

These were my files and i used nextjs, prisma supabase, server actions i tried to auth bby watching this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1MTyCvS05V4&t=6741s&ab_channel=CodeWithAntonio. i tried console the the code it shows the error ikm which crypto error please help me solve this problem or any other solution server

auth.config.ts

```
import type { NextAuthConfig } from "next-auth"
import { getUserByEmail } from "./data/user";
import { LoginSchema } from "./schemas";
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";
import Credentials from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

export default {
  providers: [ 
    Credentials({
      async authorize(credentials) {
        const validatedFields = LoginSchema.safeParse(credentials);

        if (validatedFields.success) {
          const { email, password } = validatedFields.data;
          
          const user = await getUserByEmail(email);
          if (!user || !user.password) return null;

          const passwordsMatch = await bcrypt.compare(
            password,
            user.password,
          );
          if (passwordsMatch) return user;
        }
        return null;
      }
    })
  ],
} satisfies NextAuthConfig
```

auth.ts

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import authConfig from "./auth.config";
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@auth/prisma-adapter"
import { db } from "./lib/db";
import { getUserById } from "./data/user";
import { UserRole } from "@prisma/client";

export const {
  handlers: { GET, POST },
  auth,
  signIn,
  signOut,
} = NextAuth({
  callbacks: {
    async session({ token, session }) {
      if (token.sub && session.user) {
        session.user.id = token.sub;
      }

      if (token.role && session.user) {
        session.user.role = token.role as UserRole;
      }
      return session
    },

    async jwt({ token }) {
      if (!token.sub) return token;

      const existingUser = await getUserById(token.sub);

      if (!existingUser) return token;

      return token
  },
},
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(db),
  session: { strategy: "jwt"},
  ...authConfig,
});
```

Login form

```
"use client"

import React, { useState, useTransition } from 'react'
import { CardWrapper } from './card-wrapper'
import * as z from "zod";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { LoginSchema } from "@/schemas"
import { Form, FormControl, FormField, FormItem, FormLabel, FormMessage } from '../ui/form';
import { Input } from '../ui/input';
import { Button } from '../ui/button';
import { FormError } from '../form-error';
import { FormSuccess } from '../form-success';
import { login } from '@/action/login';

const LoginForm = () => {
  const [error, setError] = useState<string | undefined>("")
  const [success, setSuccess] = useState<string | undefined>("")
  const [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition();

  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof LoginSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(LoginSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      email: "",
      password: ""
    },
  })

  const onSubmit = (values: z.infer<typeof LoginSchema>) => {
    setError("")
    setSuccess("")

    startTransition(() => {
      login(values)
        .then((data) => {
          setError(data.error);  // "data is possible 'undefined'"
          setSuccess(data.success); // "data is possible 'undefined'"

        })
    })
    
  }

  console.log(onSubmit)


  return (
    <CardWrapper
     headerLabel="welcome back"
     backButtonLabel="Don't have an account?"
     backButtonHref="/auth/register"
     showSocial
    >
        <Form {...form}>
           <form 
              onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
              className="space-y-6"
              >
                <div className="space-y-4">
                  <FormField 
                    control={form.control}
                    name="email"
                    render={({ field }) => (
                      <FormItem>
                            <FormLabel className="text-lg px-1">Email</FormLabel>
                            <FormControl>
                              <Input 
                                {...field}
                                disabled={isPending}
                                placeholder="example@example.com"
                                type="email"
                                className="text-lg"
                              />
                            </FormControl>
                            <FormMessage />
                          </FormItem>
                    )}
                  />
                  <FormField 
                    control={form.control}
                    name="password"
                    render={({ field }) => (
                      <FormItem>
                            <FormLabel className="text-lg px-1">Password</FormLabel>
                            <FormControl>
                              <Input 
                                {...field}
                                disabled={isPending}
                                placeholder="Pass@123"
                                type="password"
                              />
                            </FormControl>
                            <FormMessage />
                          </FormItem>
                    )}
                  />
                </div>
                <FormError message={error} />
                <FormSuccess message={success} />
                <Button
                disabled={isPending}
                 type="submit"
                 className="w-full text-xl"
                >
                  Login
                </Button>
           </form>
        </Form>
    </CardWrapper>
  )
}

export default LoginForm
```

terminal log

```
[auth][error] CallbackRouteError: Read more at https://errors.authjs.dev#callbackrouteerror
[auth][cause]: TypeError: "ikm"" must be an instance of Uint8Array or a string
    at normalizeUint8Array (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./node_modules/@panva/hkdf/dist/node/esm/index.js:21:47)
    at normalizeIkm (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./node_modules/@panva/hkdf/dist/node/esm/index.js:25:17)
    at hkdf (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./node_modules/@panva/hkdf/dist/node/esm/index.js:47:98)
    at getDerivedEncryptionKey (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./node_modules/@auth/core/jwt.js:144:67)
    at Object.encode (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./node_modules/@auth/core/jwt.js:62:36)
    at Module.callback (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./node_modules/@auth/core/lib/actions/callback/index.js:300:44)
    at async AuthInternal (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./node_modules/@auth/core/lib/index.js:67:24)
    at async Auth (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./node_modules/@auth/core/index.js:126:29)
    at async signIn (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./node_modules/next-auth/lib/actions.js:57:17)
    at async login (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./src/action/login.ts:28:9)
    at async E:\writeup-main\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:39:406
    at async t0 (E:\writeup-main\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:38:5773)
    at async rh (E:\writeup-main\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:39:23636)
    at async doRender (E:\writeup-main\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1391:30)
    at async cacheEntry.responseCache.get.routeKind (E:\writeup-main\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1552:28)
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseWithComponentsImpl (E:\writeup-main\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1460:28)
    at async DevServer.renderPageComponent (E:\writeup-main\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1843:24)
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseImpl (E:\writeup-main\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1881:32)
    at async DevServer.pipeImpl (E:\writeup-main\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:909:25)
    at async NextNodeServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (E:\writeup-main\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:266:17)
    at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (E:\writeup-main\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:805:17)
[auth][details]: {
  "provider": "credentials"
}
```

i console.log in user i could get user with email and password but it in password match with bcrypt how could i solve this problem i tried using both bcrypt and bcryptjs but it show this error in bcryptjs in this code and other type of error in bcrypt

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding NEXTAUTH_SECRET.

To generate the next-auth secret run this command in your terminal

```
openssl rand -base64 32
```

Then Add your secret in your .env file.

```
NEXTAUTH_SECRET="paste secret here that is generated from the above command"
```

That fixes your issue. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem,
i tried downgrading the next-auth to 5.0.0-beta.4 and it works, also don't forget to add AUTH_SECRET="secret" on your .env file

Answer (score 0):

it is the AUTH_SECRET name I had the same problem but on my .env file I used to have something different than AUTH_SECRET and when I set it back to AUTH_SECRET it works